# QGIS 3.4.11: intersecting vector data/list all land cover classen

Tags: intersection, qgsvectorlayer

I have a question regarding QGIS 3.4.11.

For research purposes I need to intersect two vector data - one polygonized raster (with land cover classes)/mulitiple polygons shp and one point shp (buffers are set at certain distances).

I want to know which land cover classes intersect with the buffers. But when i open the attribut table only one class is listed even if more classes intersect.

Fig 1 shows the intersection with the fid 1117.

Fig 1:

[image]

Fig 2 shows the atttibut table. In column DN the land cover classes are noted. As you can see in Fig 1 multiple land cover classes intersect with the buffer yet just one class is listed.

Fig 2:

[image]

How can I solve this Problem?